# How to check if date of file > local file in PHP?

Tags: php, file, date

I download a small image from a site with PHP locally to cache it, but I would like to be able to check later on if the file has been changed on the external site since it was downloaded. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the last modification time on the files:

```
if (filemtime($filename1) > filemtime($filename2)) {
    // do something
}
```